# Refactoring Windows Form designer code

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to update a single motor control application into a program that controls an unknown number of motors(adding motor controls at runtime).  The old application was written very statically and relied on windows form designer to generate its views.  I am trying to refactor the designer code to basically just display multiple occurrences each inside a Tab Page.  I am already running into errors with Windows form designer.  When I try and pull the initialization of components out into their own methods I get an error:

```
Method 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.InitializeForceIsMaintained' not found.
```

How do I tell C# I want to use the local method and not some inherited method?

I'm calling InitializeForceIsMaintained like so

```
private Void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.InitializeForceIsMaintained();
}
```

and

```
private void InitializeForceIsMaintained()
        {
            // 
            // forceIsMaintained
            // 
            this.forceIsMaintained.AutoReset = false;
            this.forceIsMaintained.Interval = 8000;
            this.forceIsMaintained.SynchronizingObject = this;
            this.forceIsMaintained.Elapsed += this.forceIsMaintained_Elapsed;
        }
```

Comment: With the code presented (assuming 1 class) that error should not happen. Please show a more complete outline.

Comment: The *one* method you should *never* change yourself is InitializeComponent().  It is auto-generated by the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand the complete problem, but you should never modify the designer code as its generated, so you'll only either lose your changes or break the designer.

Comment: Excellent point: The designer code *looks* like C# but should never be edited or modified, because the Visual Designer *parses* the code in order to do the editing. It's more like a really weird serialization format that happens to also be compilable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you inherit your objects from System.Windows.Forms.Form and then override the method in question? Then it would choose to use yours instead of the default one in the Forms.Form class.